# How to show html images witg dynamic id

Tags: php, html, css, slider

I'm kind of newbie on this and I need some more expert help. The thing is, I'm trying to use [this pure css easy slider](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/ehKpi) but the example seems to be used with static images.

In my case I'm using php to dynamically show the images so I need to use some kind of loop (I supose) to automatically generate the id's for these tags

What I want to do is the same thing at the example but with individual ids:

```
<img id="img-1" src="img.jpg" alt>
<img id="img-2" src="img.jpg" alt>
<img id="img-3" src="img.jpg" alt>
<img id="img-4" src="img.jpg" alt>
<img id="img-5" src="img.jpg" alt>
```

So I'm trying with this code:

```
<?php 
$categories = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS total,id,icon,name,image FROM categories  ORDER BY id LIMIT 8");
while($row = $categories->fetch_array()) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $image = $row['image'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $total = $row['total'];

    echo '<div id="slider">';
    for($i = 0; $i <= $total; $i++) {
        echo '<figure>
        <img class="ns-img" id="img-'.$i.'" src="'.$image.'"> 
        </figure>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
$categories->close();
?>
```

But seems that it doesn't work properly because it just show me the same first image over and over again, and the css structure just broke when these images are dynamically showed :C What could I do?

Comment: and ? what is your question ?

Comment: You have to take `<figure>` and `</figure>` out of your `for` loop

Comment: Also, when you have a `while` loop, why do you need another `for` loop?!

Comment: You really want several tags for the exactly same image or have you misspelled the example?

Comment: Can you please update your questions with a sample from the query response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sine you have a `while` loop, there is no need for the `for` loop

Also as in the sample you shared in your question, you only need 1 `<div id="slider">` and `<figure>`. So you need to move them out of your loop

Your final code should look something like this:

```
<?php 
$categories = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS total,id,icon,name,image FROM categories  ORDER BY id LIMIT 8");

$i = 1;
echo '<div id="slider"><figure>';
while($row = $categories->fetch_array()) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $image = $row['image'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $total = $row['total'];

    echo '<img class="ns-img" id="img-'.$i.'" src="'.$image.'">';
    $i++;
}
echo '</figure></div>';

$categories->close();
?>
```

Comment: Ok I tested it with this code and it looks better because the slider now keeps its structure, but it is still showing the same first id image all the time

Comment: @kukiko11 What do you mean by _showing the same first id image all the time_?

Comment: that maybe while loop is not working as it should be... I'm getting <img id="img-1"> all the time instead of <img id="img-1"> and <img id="img-2"> and <img id="img-3"> ...

Comment: @kukiko11 So you can try `echo $categories->num_rows;` before this line `$i = 1;` and see how many records you have in your resultset

Comment: You also can try `var_dump($categories);` and see what actually is in your resultset

Comment: it's done, thanks guys... It was my query, I fixed it and it worked like a charm